# Attiny85 not recognized at windows startup

Tags: usb, avr, attiny

I'm using an Attiny85 to interact with a computer using an USB connection, and everything works fine except when I restart my computer and the Attiny85 is connected. When Windows end to boot up the Attiny85 isnt't recognized, and on Device Manager it's listed like this:

[image: Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)]

If I unplug the Attiny85 and then plug it back in, everything works just fine.

Is there any to make it detectable at boot time without having to always unplug/plug it?

**EDIT:**

More details:

I'm using this board
[image: ATtiny85 USB Mini Dev Board]

and **libusb-win32** as the USB driver

Comment: The ATTiny doesn't really do USB. Making it interface with a USB port using something like V-USB is a hack at best. You shouldn't expect it to work properly in all respects.

Comment: You could use an oscilloscope and/or a USB protocol analyzer to find out what exactly V-USB does wrong, but in any case such a hacky software emulation cannot be fixed. Better use a microcontroller that actually supports USB (e.g., a Teensy).

Comment: Added more details (board and USB driver) to help in problem analyis

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputations to make a comment so I will drop my 2 cents here.

There should be more elegant way to do this but as a fast solution I would recommend two things:

1. If it is possible, add a push button to your board to reset the MCU manually when the PC is booted up.
2. You can make a software reset after powering up the board by a certain time (e.g. 10 sec) by using watchdog timer.

Comment: I can't use the button idea because the board will be inside a case, and it wouldn't be practical.

The idea about the watchdog timer won't work because the board is always connected, so when the PC is off I would be executing the reset procedure at every 10 seconds, and I don't know if it would "like it".

Comment: @GonçaloCardoso Regarding watchdog timer, you can use watchdog timer just one time. You can handle this in your code.

Comment: But at what time would that be?

Comment: @GonçaloCardoso The time completely depends on your application. To perform a software reset one time look at this [link](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrlibcreferencemanual/FAQ_1faq_softreset.html).

Comment: The problem is that I need to make the restart when Windows boots up, and I haven't managed to find a way for the board to detect it.

Comment: @GonçaloCardoso When PC is off there should be no supply at USB port. After powering up the PC your board is going to be supplied and here where you start the timer to get the MCU reset. The time should not be too long because if you plug in your board while the PC is running the board is going to start working after the time you had already set. As I told you in my answer, it is not a perfect solution and I don't know if you can manage to place a push button on your board case. Otherwise you have to dig into the V-USB code and hope that you find a way to get the job done.

Comment: @GonçaloCardoso By the way I have an idea that should work for you. Try to disable the power saving options for USB devices and then reboot and see whether it works or not. Look at this [link](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-xp-tips/prevent-windows-from-powering-off-usb-device/).